# Image array rotation

Tags: java, image-processing

I have an array representing the pixels of a grayscale image. I need an algorithm that can produce arrays of the same size that represent this image rotated at any angle, preferably without cropping any part of the image.
I've done some research and found various methods to flip images as well as some stuff on rotational matrices but I still don't have a good algorithm to do this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Why the constraint that the array must be the same size and the image can not be cropped? What happens if the image to rotate is a long thin rectangle?

Comment: you can either crop or have an array of a different size.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple for loop once you figure it out. If you are using a image processing library do tell because those solutions can be a lot faster.

```
//this function assumes a rectangular image,
// and rotates it 90 degrees right
public static Color[][] rotate(Color[][] image) {
    Color[][] newImage = new Color[image[0].length][image.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < image[0].length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < image.length; j++) {
            newImage[i][j] = image[image.length-j-1][i];
        }
    }
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to rotate any other number of degrees? Say 20.4? Also, I'm not using an image processing library but have no problem using one if you could let me know how to import and all that.

Comment: Anything other than a multiple of 90 will require some sort of cropping and antialiasing solution. it would be a pretty complex algorithm . . . 
I would recommend OpenCV, as it is reasonably popular = decent tutorials.
you can try the tutorial at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/index.htm
The page on rotation: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/opencv_rotation.htm